# Azure Function Webhook Templates

Tags: azure, azure-functions, webhooks

I'm starting to research and learn Azure Functions. Specifically I need to learn about webooks.

This video uses a template; https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/create-a-web-hook-or-api-azure-function/

I have seen this in other tutorials/post on setting up an Azure Function to handle a Github webhooks.

When I create a new function I do not have any of these templates show up. I'm assuming they may need to be uploaded but I have searched and not found any information of where they may be located and how to import them.

Are these still available to use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that video is quite old. You can find the [latest documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview) which contains quite a few quickstarts and tutorials to get you started.

Also, while you can create functions from the portal, most of the development can be done locally which is usually preferred by most. Depending on your preference, you could develop using

- [Visual Studio Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-vs-code?pivots=programming-language-csharp)
- [Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-your-first-function-visual-studio)
- [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function-azure-cli) (along with any editor of your choice :D)

Also, there are a [couple of supported languages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/supported-languages) from which you can choose from to develop for.